# Is it possible to have a collection attribute in SailsJs without using the 'via' field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

For example, if I had a 'Conversation' model a simple chat messaging system, I might do the following:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    messages: {
      collection: 'Message'
    }
  }
}
```

Is this allowed in SailsJs? If not, is it recommended to mimic a "Has" relationship from Conversation to Message by using some form of custom array? Such as below:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    messages: {
      type: 'array'
    }
  }
}
```

In a more complex scenario, my goal is to have the 'Conversation' know all of its 'Message' objects, but it is unnecessary for those 'Message' objects to know of its associated 'Conversation'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd been using that construct for quite a while but only now did I find that the official docs don't specify it.

They mention that in [one-way associations](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/one-way-association) `a model is associated with another model` and don't mention collections. (Though they should work in just the same manner.)

For [one-to-many associations](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/one-to-many) they specify that a `model can be associated with many other models` (a collection) but don't specify what happens if you ignore the `via` attribute. They simply mention it `is needed`.

However, if you simply leave out the `via` attribute, the `id` field is used as the key for the association. So the construct you specified is allowed.

On a different note, you might want to reconsider keeping `messages` as either an array or a collection. Since you might need to add/retrieve/update/remove messages in a random fashion and collections and arrays can only be accessed as a whole, it might make sense to specify a relevant index on the `Message` collection and forgo having an association. This would let you quickly run queries like "retrieve the last 10 messages of thread " and so on.